# How can I remove locust eggs from the soil, and prevent future infestations?

Tags: vegetables, pest-control, insects

A few days ago I saw a locust standing still in my little vegetable garden. I was really surprised that even though I went close it wouldn't jump away.

After looking closer I figured that it was actually "pumping" eggs into the soil (check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCR_dnB9BUs) for more details).

This morning just before watering I found find this pattern of holes, of similar size of the one that the locust left the previous time.

[image]

I have a few questions:

1. Since they are 1 day recent and I guess not really visible, how deep should I dig to make sure all eggs are removed?
2. How can I make sure that all eggs die, if in the process of digging I miss some? Should I spray the ground with something? And if yes what do you suggest (considering I also grow edible vegetables)?
3. How can I stop this locust from coming back and laying eggs in my garden? Is there any natural product that will keep it away? If not natural what should I use (again considering I grow edible vegetables)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locusts are only capable of digging 2-3 cm. deep, to lay eggs. I would dig out the soil in a two inch deep trench, along that little row. The eggs are shaped like fat rice grains, and are usually encased in a dirt capsule (see picture).

From [here](http://ipm.ncsu.edu/AG271/forages/grasshoppers.html):

> Grasshopper eggs occur in oval, elongate or curved pods made out of soil particles. Often the size of kernels of rice, eggs may be white, yellow green, tan, or various shades of brown.

Also, the eggs don't change size. They remain the same until hatching.

[image]

If you go slowly and carefully, you probably won't miss many; I wouldn't suggest spraying the ground with anything.

I've found that keeping them away doesn't usually work as well as controling them once they appear. For me, they only do minimal damage, so I only spray them when they become concentrated in one area. Next time you see a locust laying eggs, consider killing it right then. That will save you some time.